# compare passwords with bcrypt

Tags: sql, socket.io, bcrypt

Hi i have problems with comparing two passwords. it gives me this error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getPassword'). i think its because im using the row.getpassword. Any suggestions on how to fix this?
The sql statement will take the password for this specific username and compare it whit the password typed in. is it the compare function that dosen work??

```
 socket.on('existing user', function (username, password) {
    socket.username = validator.escape(username);
socket.password = validator.escape(password);

 db.serialize(async function() {
      var getPassword = `SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = "${socket.username}"`
      db.get(getPassword, function(err,row) {

        const match = bcrypt.compare(socket.password, row.getPassword);
        if(!match){

          socket.emit('passwordsnotmatch')
        }
        
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          // Compare hashed password with the password retrieved from the database
          if (match) {

            socket.emit('redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const match = bcrypt.compare(socket.password, row.password);
```

This should fix it.

Comment: it didnt fix it, it seems that i cant get the correct value from the database, any other suggestions?